# Get Quickbooks object Schema using API

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We are developing an app on QuickBooks and we need to get different Object structures.

for example Customer{
Id : String , filterable , sortable
SyncToken: String
DisplayName : String , filterable , sortable
...
}

Could anyone point us to the QuickBooks API to get data structure?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Intuit documents all of their QuickBooks APIs here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account

You'll notice there *isn't an API to get the object structure*. What you're looking for does not exist.

Intuit does publish an `.XSD` which gives you all of this information though:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/learn/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/minor-versions

Also, I would watch the Intuit Developer blog / Twitter account, because this is a common request and something that it's likely Intuit will add support for in the future (specifically, at previous `QuickBooks Connect` conferences they have hinted at adding GraphQL support, which provides all of this schema information as part of the protocol):

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/homepage